# Setting CSS to dynamically reloaded <span> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set different colors to  elements that are loaded dynamically. It is working fine initially; however, after i empty div content. div.empty() or div.html("") and reload this same div with new  text, i am unable to set colors to newly added s.

Here is what i am trying to do. The user completes activity and this loop highlights his/her answers red or green. the first time activity is loaded, everything works fine. However, when the user moves on to the next activity, where content of  is reloaded, and when user completes second part of activity, this same text color change logic does not work.

```
for (var k = 0; k < userAnswers.length; k++) {                    
    if (userAnswers[k].answer === 'correct') {                   
        $('#' + userAnswers[k].card).css({                       
            color: '449d44'                                      
        });                                                      
    } else {                                                     
        $('#' + userAnswers[k].card).css({                       
            color: '#d9534f'                                     
        });                                                      
    }                                                            
}
```

If you know of some steps that i need to do before initiating the check, please let me know. I am happy to provide more information if needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So when you empty it, you need to loop over and remove the color. It would be a lot easier to use classes.

Comment: probably you need to regenerate `userAnswers` list

Comment: You are going to have to add more code, showing when the for loop is called and how the answers are reloaded.

Comment: What about if instead of editing the css attribute you ADD or REMOVE classes? That should do the trick.

Comment: what is `userAnswers` contain?

Comment: Please provide the relevant html and css so we can help you better.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide an HTML output, so that it will be more easier for us to read. You can check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).